# Vim: Making XML text "pretty"

Tags: text-processing, vim, editors, vi, xml

Is there an easy way within `vi` to make your XML text "pretty"?

For example:

I want this..

```
            <person>
  <name>Nick</name>
 <age>26</age>
         <gender>male</gender>
<occupation>doctor</occupation>
    </person>
```

to be this...

```
<person>
    <name>Nick</name>
    <age>26</age>
    <gender>male</gender>
    <occupation>doctor</occupation>
</person>
```

Comment: If all else fails, there's always macros. `qq0dt<jq` and then `3@qj@@5k4I<space><esc>j.j.j.`. Wow, that looks pretty cryptic.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I've had the most luck with this:

```
:%!xmllint --format %
```

It's strict about your tags, though, so it will error out if your opening and closing tags don't match. It also adds an XML declaration at the top of your file, if you don't have one as well.

[This page recommends the following, although I can't get it to work:](http://tiebing.blogspot.com/2009/12/use-vim-to-auto-format-your.html)

```
:set filetype=xml
:filetype indent on
gg=G
```

I tested it out, and it seems to work, somewhat. Not perfectly, but it gets the job done.

If that doesn't work well, you could use minidom in Python to format it for you.

```
import xml.dom.minidom

xml = xml.dom.minidom.parse(filename)
formatted_xml = xml.toprettyxml()
```

Comment: That `gg=G` command didn't really work. Instead, it just removed all the previous indentations I had.

Comment: Yeah, I've found the same thing. It seems to work when I have a specific type of formatting already, but usually not. I'll have to test it out a bit more.

Comment: `:%!xmllint --format %` seems to work well, so I've added that to the post.

Comment: Do you if you can set the tab indent size? For example: A parent's children will be 1 tab instead of 3 spaces, etc.

Comment: @RobAveryIV you can set the indentation by setting the environment variable `XMLLINT_INDENT`. Default is two spaces, and you can set it to anything you want: `export XMLLINT_INDENT="    "` for four spaces, for example. See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10386006/2521769) on StackOverflow.

Comment: Only downside to `xmllint`: requires that the current buffer be saved as a filename first.

Comment: @kenny I modified the answer to cope with that

Comment: I'm doing ":set ft=xml | %!xmllint --format -" to make it work on the current buffer and turn on syntax highlighting

Comment: got an error, "E499: Empty file name for '%' or '#', only works with :p:h"